# updating a column to its default on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, default-value

My web application receives an update form for a db record, submitted by the user.

I would like to create an sql which will update all the values to exactly what the user submitted, except those which the user left blank. For those, I want the value to be set to its DB default.

Is there a way to do it?
I'm looking for something like

```
update my_table set col1=17, col2=DEFAULT, col3='some text'
```

Please notice that I'm updating an existing row, thus I cannot just live some columns out from the update sql, as they might have had a value before which needs to be erased now.

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is a [DEFAULT(col_name)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) function:

> Returns the default value for a table column. An error results if the
>   column has no default value.

```
UPDATE my_table SET col1=17, col2=DEFAULT(col2), col3='some text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently it's just that simple, exactly as I wrote:

```
update my_table set col1=17, col2=DEFAULT, col3='some text'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html